# Query for Items in a Dictionary that match a collection

Tags: c#, linq, ienumerable

Given a `Dictionary<Guid,ICollection<Item>> myDictionary`, I would like to get a return set `ICollection<Guid> matches` based on the dictionary entries that have an `ICollection<Item>` of `Item`'s matching *all* of the `Item`'s in another instance `ICollection<Item> testset`. Is there a way to boil this down to one expression?

Comment: Something like myDictionary.Where(entry => entry.Value.SequenceEqual(testset)).Select(entry => entry.Key)?  Be aware that this does not use the lookup capabilities of a dictionary.

Comment: A `Dictionary<Guid, ICollection<Item>>` is designed for retrieving an `ICollection<Item>` based upon a given `Guid`. You are trying to retrieve a `Guid` based upon a given `ICollection<Item>` instead, so are you sure you are using the appropriate data structure?

Comment: Well the broader question is: given an `ICollection<Item>`, analyze a data structure of thousands of objects which each have an `ICollection<Item>` and get us the object's Guid where all the items in the object's collection match all the items in the test collection. I'm all ears for whatever data structure you propose. I preferred to maintain the said dictionary in order not to keep the objects in memory. Once we get the Guids, the object retrieval is trivial.

Comment: @vc74 It appears you are saying the use of Dictionary is arbitrary since we are using IEnumerable methods? You are implying rework to use hashing?

Comment: If you use `HashSet<Item>` you can use very efficient methods like `IsProperSubsetOf`.